# Compare Java Beans ignoring null/empty collection differences

Tags: java, junit, javabeans

Is there a short, *generic* way, native or via a common library, to have an equals method that asserts two beans are true discarding differences in Collections field between null and empty collection? I need this for JUnit tests, so test-dependencies are okay
Example:

```
class Bus {
    private List<String> passengers;
}

@Test
public void testEmptyBussesEqual() {
    Bus bus1 = new Bus(null);
    Bus bus2 = new Bus(new ArraysList<>());
    assertTrue(specialEqual(bus1, bus2));
}
```

My best attempt so far is using AssertJ:

```
assertThat(bus1)
    .usingComparatorForType(new CustomListComparator(), List.class)
    .usingComparatorForType(new CustomMapComparator(), Map.class)
    .isEqualToComparingFieldByFieldRecursively(bus2);
```

where each Custom...Comparator ignores differences between null and empty collections, and then compares collection contents using a similar approach recursively.

The main use-case I have is mapping between DTO and domain model. DTOs may have null fields to optimize for space on the transport medium, while the domain model may prefer empty collections to avoid the NullPointerException. Mapping code has to be unit-tested, and those differences between null and empty make for unwieldy test code.
Of course, one alternative for the use-case may be to configure serialization/deserialization, but that does not help to unit-test a mapper that for the sake of robustness still maps null fields to empty collections.

Comment: If those cases are truly equal, maybe you could change null to empty list inside the constructor?

Comment: @MarcinPietraszek I added a use-case explaining background.

Answer (score 1):

May be `Unitils` library `ReflectionAssert` class will help you to resolve the problem:

```
public static void assertReflectionEquals(Object expected,
                                          Object actual,
                                          ReflectionComparatorMode... modes)
                                   throws junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
```

> Asserts that two objects are equal. Reflection is used to compare all
>   fields of these values. If they are not equal an AssertionFailedError
>   is thrown. The comparator modes determine how strict to compare the
>   values.

```
public static void assertLenientEquals(String message,
                                       Object expected,
                                       Object actual)
                                throws junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
```

> Asserts that two objects are equal. Reflection is used to compare all
>   fields of these values. If they are not equal an AssertionFailedError
>   is thrown. This is identical to assertReflectionEquals with lenient
>   order and ignore defaults set as comparator modes.

```
@Test
public void testCollectionEquals() {
    Collection<String> expected = null;
    Collection<String> actual = new ArrayList<>();
    ReflectionAssert.assertReflectionEquals(expected, actual, ReflectionComparatorMode.IGNORE_DEFAULTS);
    ReflectionAssert.assertLenientEquals("Error message", expected, actual);
}
```